# Unable to get error message sent from server in Ext.data.JsonP.request() failure

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, jsonp, response

I'm using Ext.data.JsonP.request() (Sencha 2.3.0) to make a few cross-domain JSONP calls. For example:
Code:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
  url: '/myUrl',
  success: function(...) { ... },
  failure: function(error) {... }
);
```

The problem is, Ext.data.JsonP is always passing the string "error" to the failure() handler; there's no way to get the error message provided by the backend in the response.

I checked sencha's code, in the handleError function sets request.errorType = 'error' and then sending it to the responseHandler. So, I'm only getting the "error" string in the failure handler not the message sent from the server.

So, can anybody suggest, how can I get the server response in the failure handler?

Comment: by "server response" you mean a custom handled error returned by the server (e.g. "we are currently making some ...")? or do you mean the statusText from the request (e.g not found)

Comment: Probably worth reading this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153102-the-failure-event-of-Ext.util.JSONP.request-not-work